# Using Kendo UI and NGX Bootstrap in a Angular App

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, ngx-bootstrap

I'm developing an Angular app, with [NGX-Bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/) library. I know that is better to use only one library at the same time, without mixing it with other component's libraries. I found that [Kendo UI](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui), has many interesting components too. It' possible to use both libraries in an Angular Web Application? Has anyone tried it before me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is possible, were doing it right now on a large angular project.